# What are 'matplotlib' "figure points" and how are they determined?

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, figure, axes

Though this is probably an elementary question, I'm having trouble finding an answer (the search terms aren't helping, since they generate a lot of false hits): what are 'matplotlib' "figure points" and how are they determined?

For example if I have something like

```
annotate("A note", (x_val, y_val), textcoords='offset points', xytext=(5,-5))
```

the coordinates of the annotation will be `xval+f(5)` and `yval+f(-5)`, and I'm trying to figure out what `f(.)` looks like and what parameters of the figure or axes it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

A point is just the [typographical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) or 1/72 of an inch. In terms of pixels, it would be points/72 * *display dpi*. `figure points` would refer to an offset in points from the boundary of the figure itself while the `offset points` you show in the annotate example refers to an offset relative to the x/y coordinate provided.